# Do While Loop not giving me correct output string

Tags: ms-access, while-loop, vba, do-while

I'm trying to assign a list of Names to a combobox control in Access VBA.

My problem is that the output string of names is not correct.

Here is my code:

```
Private Sub command186_click()
    Dim firstName As String
    Dim lastName As String
    Dim rst As Object
    Dim rowSourceText As String
    Dim fullName As String

    Set rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Pool_Contact")

    Do While Not rst.EOF
        firstName = rst("FName").Value
        lastName = rst("LName").Value
        fullName = firstName + " " + lastName
        rst.MoveNext
    Loop

    Forms(FrmDaysAvailable).Controls("Combo202").rowSource = fullName
    Debug.Print fullName
End Sub
```

I know that the error is somewhere inside of my loop, where the variable fullName is written over by the second result.

how can I fix this loop to produce a string that looks like fullName , fullName, fullName ...

Thanks for all your help

Comment: Isn't ``rst("FName").Value`` would be ``rst.fields("FName").Value``?

Comment: That's not the problem. If I place the debug inside of the loop right after the `rst.MoveNext`, `debug.print fullName` gives me the list of names separated by a line feed.

Comment: I see you've named the form "frmDaysAvailable" it would also be good practice to rename your combobox to something other than "Combo202" for when your reading the code back.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must add each item to the ComboBox, instead you are only adding the last one

```
Do While Not rst.EOF
    firstName = rst("FName").Value
    lastName = rst("LName").Value
    fullName = firstName & " " & lastName
    Me!Combo202.AddItem(fullName)
    rst.MoveNext
Loop
```

Also you should declare `rst` as `DAO.Recordset` not as object. (You might have to add a reference to the DAO dll).

Optionally you can assign a table or a query directly to the row source of the ComboBox and drop the loop completely

```
Me!Combo202.RowSource = "Pool_Contact"
```

But you can do that in the form designer and do not need to do it in VBA at all. If you need to refresh the contents of the ComboBox you can simply write

```
Me!Combo202.Requery
```

Note: I assume that `Forms(FrmDaysAvailable)` is the current form. In that case you can simply address it through `Me`. Further, the `Controls` collection is the default property of a form. `Forms(FrmDaysAvailable).Controls("Combo202")` can be simplyfied to `Me("Combo202")` or even to `Me!Combo202` with the VBA collection access operator `!`.

I also suggest you to give your ComboBox (and other controls) meaningful names like `cboFullName`. This makes the code more readable. I usually make a query corresponding to the ComboBox with the same name prefixed with "q": `qcboFullName` and assign this to the RowSource of the combo in the properties window. A query has the advantage over a table that you can apply a "ORDER BY" and select exactly the columns needed for the ComboBox.

Typically you would have a hidden ID column (enter 0 in the column width property) as result of the user selection and a string column for display.

```sql
SELECT PersonID, firstName & ' ' & lastName AS Display
FROM tblPerson
ORDER BY firstName, lastName
```

Comment: I wouldn't use + to concatenate. Also, why loop through the recordset? This is MS Access.

Comment: Do you think it is a good idea to set the row source to a table? How will you control the column count, size and order?

Comment: @Remou: In most cases you will have a query as row source; however, in simple cases where you have a lookup table with non changing values (e.g. month numbers and month names) or a table with temporary results that are sorted, a table would work.

Comment: I am aware of that, but the OP made it clear that the names were to be concatenated to give a full name, so the table is not limited to an ID and description, or a single column, therefore setting the RowSource to a table name cannot be correct in this instance. You have drawn a lot on my answer, you may as well use that as well.

Comment: @Remou: I looked at your answer only after I had written my own. Obviously the OP does not use an ID at all. The question is what he wants to do with the selected name. In most scenarios a name alone is of no use. If you want to select a person, you need to know its ID to process it further. This might be a design error of the OP.

Answer (score 5):

This can be a lot simpler:

```
 Forms(FrmDaysAvailable).Controls("Combo202").rowSource = _
           "SELECT ID, FName & ' ' & LName FROM Pool_Contact"
```

Or

```
Forms!FrmDaysAvailable.Combo202.rowSource = _
           "SELECT ID, FName & ' ' & LName FROM Pool_Contact"
```

Or

```
Me.Combo202.rowSource = "SELECT ID, FName & ' ' & LName FROM Pool_Contact"
```

Furthermore, use & not + to concatenate. Plus (+) will give you problems with nulls.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work. rather than names in my combobox, I have _"Select ID"_ and _"FName & ' ' & LName FROM Pool_Contact"_. It is interpreting what you wrote as a string and not an index to the FName and LName of pool_Contact. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Have you set the row source type to value list? It should be table/query for the above.

Comment: still not working. I changed it to table/query, and now my debug for `Debug.Print Me.Combo202.Value` gives me null. I want to use this method for its simplicity, but its giving me problems

Comment: Did you really change my sample line to `"Select ID" and "FName & ' ' & LName FROM Pool_Contact"`? It should read `"Select ID, FName & ' ' & LName FROM Pool_Contact"`. It is an SQL string, exactly the same as your recordset. This is the usual way to populate a combo in MS Access, and the way the combo wizard will build it.